# Remotely Detect Connection Status of Android Phone

Tags: android, android-wifi, google-voice

I have an android phone that I am using on Page Plus. I am trying to figure out the best way to remotely detect (from a linux webserver) whether or not the device is connected to a wifi network.

I want to disable sms forwarding on my google voice account when not connected to wifi, but since my phone does not have a data connection, this has to be triggered remotely. I know how to program the forwarding setting toggle function, I just need to remotely detect the android device wifi state.

I have thrown around a few ideas, such as monitoring the gtalk status of the phone, and detecting if the android client is online - I can sort of get this to work, but it isn't the cleanest approach in the world.

Any recommendations, or ideas?  I know this isn't exactly a programming question, but I would love some help!

Comment: are you able to run code on the client (phone)?

Comment: Yes, I am able to run code on the client. I would just have the phone disable the forwarding setting itself on wifi disconnection, but that is impossible since I don't have network access after disconnecting from the wifi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run a background service on the Android client which pings the webserver at constant time intervals whenever wifi is connected - whenever the client misses a "scheduled" check-in, the webserver concludes that the phone is disconnected, and executes whatever actions you want in that case.

To ping the server, I would use a simple TCP socket:

```
// you could use IP address instead of the hostname if you don't have a domain name
// PORT_NUM is some value shared between the server and the client e.g. 3456
Socket sock = new Socket("mywebserverurl.com", PORT_NUM);
OutputStream out = sock.getOutputStream();
String data = getDataServerNeeds();
out.write(data.getBytes());
sock.close();
```

[This tutorial](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/simple-connection-example-part-ii-tcp-communication) has a more detailed example, including the server-side aspect.

Comment: What kind of battery life implications would that have? Would one ping a minute impact battery life very much?

Comment: you could probably run an experiment to check this more rigorously, but I would imagine that one ping per minute while connected to wifi would have a trivial impact on battery life. consider that while wifi is connected, your phone is generally sending/receiving lots of data, so one tiny message probably won't be killer.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting idea - Obviously I want minimal data usage for the ping - any ideas on the best way to do this? HTTP would have a decent amount of overhead - would a custom tcp connection of some sort make more sense?

Comment: I would simply open a TCP socket to the server. If the server needs information from the client, then you can send that minimal information. I'll edit a code example into the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the code - I'm working on tying everything together right now. I'll try to report back at some port with the battery impact of this.